# Изменение содержимого окна

Tags: java

Что-то я не дочитал про Свинг, MVC и JAVA вцелом :(

Прошу помочь разобраться.
Есть фрейм, в нем есть текстовое поле и кнопка. По кнопке вызывается некий класс, который что-то делает и при этом увеличивает некий счетчик. Значение счетчика нужно отображать в текстовом поле фрейма по мере его (счетчика) изменения.

Как передать это значение в вызвавший класс? Есть подзрение, что тут как-то связано с литнером, но опыта не хватает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создай внутренний класс. В нем видны переменные из главного класса

Comment: Спасибо, я так в итоге и сделал. Долго пытался сделать чето типа обсервера, но пошел по легкому пути.